# Почему не останавливается Coroutine?

Tags: unity3d

```
public void ReDeletePlatforms(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    Debug.Log("Нажал");
    StopCoroutine(spawning);
    Debug.Log("Остановил корутину");
    destroyPlatforms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Platform");
    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < destroyPlatforms.Length; i3++)
    {
        Instantiate(destroyPlatforms[i3], destroyPlatforms[i3].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        destroyPlatforms[i3].gameObject.tag = "PlatfomRealy";
        Destroy(destroyPlatforms[i3]);
    }
    StartCoroutine(Spawning());
}

public IEnumerator Spawning()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //Debug.Log(i);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        int plNumber = Random.Range(0, platforms.Length);
        float posX = Random.Range(DownLeft.x, DownRight.x);
        float posY = Random.Range(DownRight.y, UpRight.y);
        Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(posX, posY, 0);
        Instantiate(platforms[plNumber], vector3, Quaternion.identity);
        if (i == 3)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Stopped!");
            StopCoroutine("Spawning");
            Destroying();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот метод сверху, он корутину не останавливает, только создает объекты (или стартует ещё раз корутину на 1 цикл) и не меняет тег. Снизу сама корутина. А вот ещё список переменных, которые я объявил

```
public GameObject[] platforms;
public GameObject[] destroyPlatforms;
public Vector3 DownLeft;
public Vector3 DownRight;
public Vector3 UpLeft;
public Vector3 UpRight;
//Coroutine co = StartCoroutine(myEnum.GetEnumerator());
private Coroutine spawning;
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Специально для людей, в документации есть примеры кода: [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html).

Но в твоём случае достаточно просто, тупо выйти из цикла обычным `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы остановить корутину, нужно просто закончить функцию. Т.е. не нужно вызывать никаких дополнительных методов, просто дай коду дойти до конца функции, и она остановится. (функцией я подразумеваю код самой корутины)

Comment: Там в конце вызывается метод Destroying, который её заново запускает